# Accessing specified Element of Array with Twig

Tags: php, html, arrays, templates, twig

I have the following array and i want to access the value of a specified element with twig.

```
numbers => Array ([01234567] => Array ( [0] => 9876543210 [1] => 8765432109 [2] => 0000000000))
```

I know there is only one entry in `numbers`, so I want to access the array with the key `01234567` directly.

Even tough `numbers|keys[0]` does return the correct key, I can't use it like `numbers[numbers|keys[0]]` to get the array. I also tried the `attribute(array, item)` function, but i didn't got it to work.

Is it possible to access it directly or do I need to use loops?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Does the current function work? http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Comment: Is it possible to use php functions in twig templates?

Comment: It is, if you write a custom twig extension, but that's probably not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a probably undocumented "feature" of Twig. If you check [the source code](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Template.php#L340), twig tries to determine if the given key is numeric, or not. It does this check with the [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function, which checks if a variable contains only numeric characters.

The example in your question contains an array key, which meets this conditions: it contains only numbers. Unfortunately, it also starts with a zero, which is removed when the string is converted into an integer.

I'm not exactly sure that this is intended behavior, so you may try to report this example as a bug.

For the current twig implementation, because everything except the loop construct uses the getAttribute function, you have no other choice but to use a for loop.

Comment: Does this work for you? For me it doesn't, when I use {{array_item}} it doesn't show anything.

Comment: wow, twig removes the first zero from the number, I haven't expected this, even when I force a string concatenation (e.g. {% set array_item = numbers[index_var] %} still generates an exception)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, i am going to report it "tomorrow".